# How to show a list of changed files since last commit if there was a merge?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, merge, git-merge

I've been using the following command to see a list of files which changed since the previous commit, and for the most part it works.

```
git show --oneline --name-only HEAD | tail -n +2
```

However, consider this case.

The repository is cloned in two places. Person A deletes a file from the repo called foo and pushes his changes up to the repo. After that person b deletes a file from the repo called bar and tries to push up his changes. He is notified that he has to do a pull. He does a pull and he has to merge. After the merge, he pushes up his changes.

The git show command above will not show any information about the files foo or bar. There is a similar command I can use,

```
git show --oneline --stat | head -n -1 | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}'
```

But this will only list the file foo and not bar.

What git command can I run to show that the file bar was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show object` displays the object such as a commit. In the situation you explained, adding the two files and the merge happened in three separate commits. A simple way to see it is to use `git log` and use the flag `n` to limit the number of previous commits:

```
git log --oneline --name-only -n 3
```